# How can I approach the target temperature as fast as possible given the transfer function?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, inverse-laplace

I have an electric heater and close to it a temperature sensor. And I could use some help with controlling the heater.

The amount of power supplied to the heater can be changed at any moment. Let $0 \le u(t) \le 1$ be the relative amount of power supplied to the heater at time $t$.

Let $y(t)$ be the temperature of the sensor minus the environment temperature.

By doing some modelling, measurements, curve fitting and die-hard mathematics, I came to the conclusion that the relation between $u(t)$ and $y(t)$ can be approximately described using a transfer function.
$$
 \begin{align}
  \hat{f}(s) &= \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st} \ \mathrm{d}t \qquad \text{(Laplace transform)} \\
  G(s) &= \frac{0.595}{s^3+0.489 s^2+0.0613 s+0.000859} \qquad \text{(transfer function)} \\
  \hat{y}(s) &= G(s)\hat{u}(s)
 \end{align}
$$
Eventually I want to use a feedback mechanism to control $u(t)$ in order to let $y(t)$ reach a target temperature. For now, I'm interested in open loop control. Let's assume the model above is not an approximation, but is exactly correct.

If $y(0) = 0$ and a target temperature $y_T > 0$ is given, what function $u(t)$ should I choose to minimize the error $E$ while keeping $y(t) \le y_T$ at all times?
$$
E = \int_0^\infty y_T - y(t) \ \mathrm{d}t
$$
I know that eventually the steady state must be reached, so:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} u(t) = \frac{y_T}{G(0)}
$$
For example, with target $y_T = 200$, I could use this function:
$$
u(t) = \begin{cases}
1 & t < 21.33 \\
\frac{y_T}{G(0)} \approx 0.29 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I got the number $21.33$ by trying out different numbers and picking the highest number that does not make $y(t)$ exceed $y_T$. Here is the plot of $y(t)$:

[image: Plot of y(t)]

However, from more experiments I know this is not the optimal solution. The area between the blue and the orange line, $E$, can be made smaller.

Comment: Just try to use a PI controller (which should be possible) so that you have an appropriate settling-time and robustness properties. Do not try to minimize a criterion (for now).

Comment: My question is how to minimize a criterion. Telling me to do something else does not help me with finding the answer.

Comment: @Paul, Finding the open-loop input signal $u(t)$ such that the criterion is minimized is an optimal control problem. Are you searching for a formulated function of time like this $u(t) = 1.87 e^{-1.543 t}\cos(0.7705 t) - 1.053 e^{-0.5697 t}\sin(0.7974 t)$ such that the criterion $E$ is minimized? Try testing it to see if the output is expected.

Comment: @XegaXam Exactly, a formula for $u(t)$, if possible, would be perfect. Your formula does not seem to make a lot of sense though, since $\lim_{t \to \infty} u(t) = 0$ and the $0 \le u(t) \le 1$ constraint is not satisfied.

Comment: @Paul, your sense is correct. The control input was found based on unconstrained $u(t)$. It minimizes the quadratic cost function, but not your criterion $E$. For constrained $u(t) \in [0, 1]$, you can try using the Model Predictive Controller.

Comment: With three exponents in the convolution, it is always one or two full power boosts followed by some periods of waiting at zero power, after which the desired temperature is achieved and has to be maintained by solving a 3 by 3 system of ODE. The problem is how to decide whether one has to use one or two boosts and how to find them numerically. I'll have to think a bit here...

Comment: @fedja KBS is saying that the optimal solution is always full or no power. Are you saying that is incorrect?

Comment: @Paul That's correct *until you reach the desired temperature*. After that you can maintain it smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal control input that solves the optimal control problem

$$\min_{u(\cdot)\in[0,1]}\int_0^T(y_T-y(s))ds$$ such that $y(t)\le y_T$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ does not have a closed-form expression because the optimal control input is a bang-bang control since the optimization problem is linear. A direct numerical optimization approach with discretization step of 10ms yields the following solution

[image: Optimal Control Input and Output Trajectory]

where the control input is in blue (and multiplied by 100 to make it easily readable) and the corresponding temperature trajectory is in blue. The minimum cost is given by 3641.9, up to solution accuracy. Things are starting to get a bit off a bit before 40s because the input starts taking intermediary values while it should not. This is likely a numerical issue.

If we reduce the discretization step to 1ms, we get the following results

[image]

where we can observe the expected chattering behavior for the control input. This chattering phase has an average value of 0.2887 which is equal to $y_T/G(0)$.

In the end, OP is not too far from the optimal with their simple control strategy.

---

This is work under progress and may not be completely correct. I will update it when I find a bit of time.

However, it may still be possible to find an implicit characterization of the optimal control input using Pontryagin's Maximum Principle.

To do so, let us consider the system in state-space form $(A,B,C,D)$. By the Maximum Principle we get that necessary conditions are given by

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}^*(t)&=&Ax^*(t)+Bu^*(t),\ x^*(0)=x_0\\
\dot{\lambda}^*(t)&=&-A^T\lambda^*(t)+C^T-\mu(t)C^T,\ \lambda^*(T)=0
\end{array}
$$
where $\mu(t)$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated with the constraint $y(t)-y_T\le0$.

We also have the condition that $$y_T-Cx^*(t)+(Ax^*(t)+Bu^*(t))^T\lambda^*(t)+\mu(t)(y(t)-y_T)\le y_T-Cx^*(t)+(Ax^*(t)+Bu(t))^T\lambda^*(t)+\mu(t)(y(t)-y_T)$$ for all $u(t)\in[0,1]$. This means that

$$
u^*(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
0,&&\mathrm{if\ }B^T\lambda^*(t)>0\\
1,&&\mathrm{if\ }B^T\lambda^*(t)<0\\
?,&&\mathrm{if\ }B^T\lambda^*(t)=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where the question mark indicates that further analysis is needed in this case (singular arcs).

We have that

$$
\lambda^*(t)=-\int_{0}^{T-t}\exp(A^Ts)C^Tds+\int_t^T\exp(-A^T(t-s)C^T\mu(s)ds.
$$

Therefore, we have that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
B^T\lambda^*(t)&=&\displaystyle B^T\left(-\int_{0}^{T-t}\exp(A^Ts)C^Tds+\int_t^T\exp(-A^T(t-s)C^T\mu(s)ds.\right)\\
%
&=&\displaystyle -\int_0^{T-t}h(s)ds+\int_0^{T-t}h(s)\mu(t+s)ds\\
&=&\displaystyle \int_0^{T-t}h(s)(\mu(t+s)-1)ds.
\end{array}
$$

Now we face the difficulty of computing $\mu$ which must satisfy the complementary slackness condition of the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, that is, we must have that

$$\mu(t)(y(t)-y_T)=0,$$ for all $t\in[0,T]$.

In other words, we have to solve $\mu(\cdot)$ in the system

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}^*(t)&=&Ax^*(t)+Bu^*(t),\ x^*(0)=x_0\\
u^*(t)&=&\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
0,&&\mathrm{if\ }\int_0^{T-t}h(s)(\mu(t+s)-1)ds>0\\
1,&&\mathrm{if\ }\int_0^{T-t}h(s)(\mu(t+s)-1)ds<0\\
?,&&\mathrm{if\ }\int_0^{T-t}h(s)(\mu(t+s)-1)ds=0
\end{array}\right.\\
\mu(t)(Cx(t)-y_T)&=&0.
\end{array}
$$

That does not look really solvable analytically. I am currently working on it.

Comment: This looks good! Interesting that bang-bang control is optimal. I'll try to understand the second part.

Comment: Please wait a little bit for the second part. It is not complete and, therefore, not fully correct. It is an application of the maximum principle, but that does not work if we do not consider the constraint $y(t)\le y_T$ in the design. I thought I could ignore it at first, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: "the input starts taking intermediary values while it should not" - Are you sure about this? Fedja says otherwise in a comment.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that and Fedja does not say otherwise. This person says that it can be maintained to a constant level by setting the input to a constant value but that this is not necessarily the solution to that optimal control problem which basically chatters. But we can maintain that value by setting after that time the input to $y_T/G(0)$. This is, indeed, much more well-posed to do that.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit. This answer is not good as the input goes to negative values and this will be the case for most of the values for $a$. So, this is not acceptable. I am working on a fix but I am pessimistic that this approach can be fixed in an elegant way. I will delete this reply if I cannot solve this issue.**

One possible way that it not really recommended due to lack of robustness, is to use a model inversion and define the Laplace transform of the input to be

$$U(s)=\dfrac{H(s)}{G(s)}\dfrac{y_T}{s}$$

where $H(s)$ is the desired transfer which is chosen such that $U(s)$ is stable and proper. For instance,

$$H(s)=\dfrac{a^3}{(s+a)^3},\ a>0$$

as this transfer function will not yield any overshoot. Then, $a$ can be chosen such that $u(t)\in[0,1]$. An empirical search yields $0.84$ for $y_T=1$, the limiting factor being in the input saturation. In that case, the settling-time, is around 7.5 time units. Of course, this is not globally optimal as we do not search among all possible inputs but only inputs of the form given above.

The time-domain signal can be obtained using the inverse Laplace transform to get

$$
u(t)=0.001444y_T-\mathrm{e}^{-at}\left(0.001444y_T-1.681a^3y_T\right)-0.5t^2\mathrm{e}^{-at}\left(-1.681y_Ta^5+0.8218y_Ta^4-0.103y_Ta^3+0.001444y_Ta^2\right)-t\mathrm{e}^{-at}\left(3.361y_Ta^4-0.8218y_Ta^3+0.001444y_Ta\right).
$$

Since function is less than 1 if $u(0)=1.681a^3y_T\le1$. So, $a\le(1.681y_T)^{-3}$. The fastest time response is obtained whenever $a=(1.681y_T)^{-3}$.

Solving the problem in its generality involves using Pontryagin's maximum principle and direct optimization methods.